# ArcGIS JS API: Convert ESRI Date Type into String

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am [following this ESRI tutorial](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/#sample/fl_query_related) to display information from a related table for the selected features. The example in itself for my project works fine, however, **my data include two Date fields** and when I display them on the right side grid, I see something like "1237507200000" as starting date and "1237161600000" as ending date.

I understand I have to format this `esriFieldTypeDate` so I can display it as a text field like "YYYY-MM-DD", but I don't know how. It is **important to highlight** that this related records are stored in a `dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore` as in the example.

Please, does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"1237507200000" is a  date in tics, just use a regular js-date object to convert to string.
When you map the items object from feature.attributes object, you can do the conversion.
For example something like this:

```
var items = dojo.map(fset.features, function(feature) {
            var dataAttr = new Date(  feature.attributes.date )
            feature.attributes.date = dataAttr.toLocaleString() ;
            return feature.attributes;
          });

 var data = {
            identifier: "OBJECTID",  //This field needs to have unique values
            label: "OBJECTID", //Name field for display. Not pertinent to a grid but may be used elsewhere.
            items: items
          };

          //Create data store and bind to grid.
          store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data:data });
          grid.setStore(store);
          grid.setQuery({ OBJECTID: '*' });
        });
```

Comment: Rather than looping through all of the features I would use a formatter on the field. For a large dataset you are adding an uncesssary loop through the data. See Formatter on http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html

Comment: Thanks, it simply works perfectly!! I changed the date modifier to "datePattern: 'MMMM d, y' " to match my criteria. :-)